# Angular service and injecting the values

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular app and I want to retain some values between controllers using angular service

Here is my base controller:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.router"]);

    app.controller("BaseCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$state", BaseControllerFunc]);

    function BaseControllerFunc($scope, $http, $state) {
    ....

    }



})();
```

Now I want to add a service I can later fill with key-value pair data. So I tried adding the following:

```
app.service("DataService", function () {
    var data_item = {};
    data_item.Key =MyKey;
    data_item.Value=MyValue;
    this.MyData.push(data_item);

});
```

and now it looks like this:

```
(function () {
    var app = angular.module("MyApp", ["ui.router"]);

    app.controller("BaseCtrl", ["$scope", "$http", "$state", BaseControllerFunc]);

    function BaseControllerFunc($scope, $http, $state) {
    ....

    }

    app.service("DataService", function () {
       var data_item = {};
       data_item.Key =MyKey;
       data_item.Value=MyValue;
       this.MyData.push(data_item);

    });


})();
```

Here I am stuck. How would I go about injecting values (MyKey and MyValue) into my service? I am newbie with Angular so that makes it hard

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding functions to handle your data.

```
app.service("DataService", function () {
   var myData = [];

   function addItem(key, value){
       var data_item = {Key: key, Value: value);
       myData.push(data_item);
   }

   function getData(){
       return myData;
   }

   return {
       add: addItem,
       get: getData
   }

});
```

In your controller, use it like

```
DataService.add('key', 'value');
DataService.get();
```

Answer (score 0):

change it to

```
 app.service("DataService", function () {
var data_item = {};
return{
   function somename(MyKey,MyValue){

   data_item.Key =MyKey;
   data_item.Value=MyValue;
   this.MyData.push(data_item);
   }
  }
});
```

and from your controller call it as

```
DataDervice.somename(MyKey,MyValue)
```

Comment: Where do i put this code? I tried adding you code in the same place I added my code above and it underlines the return function name `somename`